# How to modify the mean and variance/dispersion of a given distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, quantiles, characteristic-function

I am trying to find a parametric adjustment that allows modifying the mean and variance/dispersion of a given distribution.

Ideally, this adjustment would be implemented through a parametric function which, **multiplied by the pdf or cdf** of the original distribution, produces the desired mean or dispersion shift.

Is there any adjustment (even if approximate) that may achieve this?

(A possible solution could involve *Probability Weighting Functions*, but I am not sure if this approach can deliver the required mean or variance shift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the mean and variance, consider the following equations (scaling and shifting.)

**Scaling**: multiplying $x$ by constant $c$

$$
mean(cx)=c \times mean(x)=c\mu\\
std(cx)=\sqrt{c^2 var(x)}=\sqrt{c^2\sigma^2}=c\sigma
$$

**Shifting**: adding constant $c$ to $x$

$$
mean(x+c)=mean(x) + c =\mu + c\\
std(x+c)=\sqrt{var(x) + var(c)} = \sqrt{\sigma^2+0}=\sigma
$$

Update: 
to keep the mean unchanged while scalling the variance/std, follow the following steps

Let the $x$ is scaled by $c$, which gives $c\mu$
 and $c\sigma$. Then to scale back the mean to $\mu$, shift it by $k = (1-c)\mu$. The final distribution will have $\mu_{new}= \mu$, and $\sigma_{new}= c\sigma$

Comment: Thank you, **Shifting** is clear: it changes the mean without affecting std. However, the **Scaling** change the std but also impact the mean. How can we do the scaling without affecting the mean?

Comment: Can always scale first to get the desired std then shift back to the original mean.

Comment: Let the x is scaled by c, which gives c*mean and c*std. Then to adjust the mean, shift it by k = (1-c)*mean. The final distribution will have mean_new= mean, and std_new= c*std

Answer (score 2):

Did you think of just adding the desired mean shift to the Standardization (or normalization) equation.

[image]

I think that is a simple solution and will shift the distribution to whatever you desire.

It would be great if you shared the use case that such a method will be applied to in order to get a better understanding.

Comment: This is the right idea, but it's incomplete, because $z$ will necessarily have *unit* variance rather than the intended variance.

Comment: Yes, (Z)  will keep (X) distribution (Unit Variance).
but all the whole distribution will be shifted number equal to shift parameter.

Comment: The question asks also about modifying the "variance/dispersion," too.

Comment: multiply by the desired dispersion before adding the shift. Now you have it!